autokey multi-tap and hold functionality
I can't find a way to use multi-taps and/or tap and hold keys on the keyboard using autokey.
On Windows using AHK and TapHoldManager, I can do the following:

Tap key on keyboard > action 1
Double tap key on keyboard > action 2
Tap and hold key on keyboard > move mouse and hold left mouse button until I release the keyboard key
Double tap and hold key on keyboard > move mouse to a different position and hold left mouse button until I release the keyboard key

Is there a way to do this in Debian using autokey?
Thanks!
